# Why this isn't working in regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expressions. I am testing an iterative regular expression. For the first time it works but second time pattern isn't initializing again.

Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String  a[])
    {
        String s="1+2+4*5*tan(tan(30))-5.8+tan(30)";
        Pattern p;
        Matcher m;  
        while(s.contains("tan("))
        {
            double[] x=new double [5];  
            p=Pattern.compile("tan\\([0-9]+\\)");
            m=p.matcher(s);
            int i=0;

            while(m.find())
            {

                System.out.println(m.group());
                x[i]=Math.tan(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(m.group().replace("tan(","").replace(")",""))));
                i++;
            }


            for(int z=0;z<i;z++)
            {
                s=s.replaceFirst("tan\\([0-9]+\\)",""+x[z]);


            }
         }
         System.out.println(s);

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*...pattern isn't initializing again*"? What behaviour you ware expecting and what did you observe instead?

Comment: when the loop runs for second time p=Pattern.compile("tan\\([0-9]+\\)"); is not working

Comment: Which loop? There are 3. What's the definition of "not working"?

Comment: Please explain ["is not working"](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: Why use regex for this? [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

Comment: I mean loop is working but pattern is not matching again . while(s.contains("tan("))  this loop .

Comment: If u run the code I think it will be clear

Comment: Wait, are you trying to calculate the `tan(x)` result and paste it back into the `s` string? You only need one loop here. However, then you **must** have a look at [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your regex.

```
"tan\\([0-9]+\\)"
```

This will not accept decimal numbers. Hence the first two tan(30) gets resolved, but then the tan(decimal numbers) is not passing the regex and it keeps going on in a loop.